# instafeed.js + scrollForever не хочет крутиться каруселька

Tags: jquery, прокрутка, instagram

Скрипты instafeed.js + scrollForever подключаются в хедере сайта.

Ссылка на сайт https://codeshare.io/aJpjwq

Формирую блок изображений из инстаграмма с помощью скрипта instafeed.js. (В коде страницы указывается div с id и все "внутренности" формируются скриптом).

Перед закрытием  добавлен код работы скроллера scrollForever.

В итоге должно быть что-то такое (1-й скроллер)

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Infinite-Any-Content-Scroller-scrollForever/

Код (более полный можно увидеть в коде страницы по 1-й ссылке):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var feed = new Instafeed({
get:"user",
userId: ##########, // Instagram ID
accessToken:"###############################", // Instagram AT
limit: 30,
resolution:"standard_resolution",
template: `'<li><a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /><div class="instainfo"><div class="instadiv"><span class="instaspan">FOLLOW ME ON <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></span></div></div></a></li>'`
});
feed.run();
</script>
<div id="instagram-area" class="a">
<!-- Instafeed  -->
<ul id="instafeed"></ul>
<!-- End Instafeed  -->
</div>
....
<!-- Instagramm scroller Plugin initialization -->
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
$(function(){
// var time1 = new Date;
$("#instagram-area").scrollForever({delayTime:30});  
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
<!-- End Instagramm scroller Plugin initialization -->
</body>
```

Все, что внутри

```html
<ul id="instafeed"></ul>
```

формируется скриптом instafeed.

Сравнил с примером, у меня для блока контейнера скрипт выставляет style="width: 0px;"...

Как его поправить, чтобы закрутился?

Comment: Я не понял как то что на вашем сайте смотреть? немного можно подробно? и с кодами ?

Comment: Добавил код в описание, но лучше в коде страницы смотреть )

Comment: тогда скажите на каком блоке должны загрузиться ваши картинки?

Comment: ul id="instafeed" - картинки загружаются, мне нужно, чтобы картинки перемещались как бегущая строка... Может scrollForever не срабатывает из-за того, что сам блок с картинками формируется динамически (яваскриптом)? Но код формирования самого блока картинок расположен выше по странице, чем код организации карусели...

Comment: инициализируй `scrollForever` после загрузки картинок.

Comment: Дак так и есть. Сначала формирую сам блок, а скролл аж перед закрытием боди стоит...

Comment: нет это не значит то что я говорил , ты путаешь, скрипты читаются браузером и по строчно обрабатываются если один скрипт работает дольше это не значит что другой ждет окончания первого, они работают паралельно.

Comment: Да, такая мысль была. А как можно сделать,чтобы скрипт скроллера дожидался окончания формирования инстаграм блока ? sync/async ?

Comment: конкретно с этим `instagram api` я не работал, но посмотри вдруг там есть что то типа `success` что бы было возможность отследить когда оно загрузил фотки, и в нем уже сделай `call` твоего `scrollForever`

Comment: Есть конструкция after... Подключил скроллер в скрипт instafeed... те же яйца, прописывает в стиль для ul ширину 0px :( карусель не крутиться...

https://codeshare.io/5OK14r

Comment: У тебя `<ul id="instafeed"></ul>` а в `js` написал `$("#instagram-area")`?

Comment: Не там как раз контейнером является родительский блок для ul - вот же демку давал http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Infinite-Any-Content-Scroller-scrollForever/

Answer (score 0):

Напортачил в обрамлении кода для устранения ошибок jquery. Из-за этого и не крутилось...

Подсказали на форуме по яваскрипт javascript.ru. Теперь все работает.

```html
var feed = new Instafeed({
get:"user",
userId: ########, // Instagram ID
accessToken:"#################", // Instagram AT
limit: 30,
resolution:"standard_resolution",
template: '<li><a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /><div class="instainfo"><div class="instadiv"><span class="instaspan">FOLLOW ME ON <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></span></div></div></a></li>',
after: function() {
   jQuery("#instagram-area").scrollForever();
}
});
jQuery(function() {
  feed.run();
});
```